# Appscan detected hidden directory for hostname/manager

Tags: tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

Appscan called  api with url **https://10.106.215.110/manager** in my application which says 403 access denied.
Now I want to change this message to 404.

Can anyone guide me. Thanks in advance.

PS I have two application running in this hostname. I am using tomcat as server and I dont want to change anything in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Changing status code can be done in the code itself if you don't want to change anything in tomcat.

public void sendError(int code, String message) 
The sendError method sends a status code (usually 404) along with a short message that is automatically formatted inside an HTML document and sent to the client.

Please refer the following link if it is a Java code: 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29817&seqNum=7

There is way in php as well.

int http_response_code ([ int $response_code ] )

You can find more about this method in the php documentation manual.

Comment: The question it self seems to be off-topic here.

Comment: It should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The hidden directory enumeration issue exists when the server responds with a '403 Forbidden' error while trying to access a valid application directory. Hidden directories were detected by viewing the '403 Forbidden' response from the server. An attacker will try to access multiple directories within the application by guessing their names or launching a brute force attack. The server will typically respond with a '404 Not Found' error if a directory does not exist, however if a valid directory exists, the server responds with '403 Forbidden' error. The attacker can use this difference in the response to enumerate the application directories and file structure. The presence of hidden directories allows an attacker to gather information regarding the file and directory structure of the application by viewing the '403 Forbidden' server response. An attacker can list the server directories by studying the different error responses that are thrown by the application server.

The Solution for this is making custom error pages with the help of web.config file.

At this moment developer can handle how users are shown a better error page by configuring  in web.config page. There are couple of attributes we need to set.
Please check below link for more details.

**https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/092589/custom-error-page-in-Asp-Net/**

Thanks